# .click does not fire client-side validation in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I have a Create page with an MVC Html.BeginForm with input controls and a submit button (id = "myButton") inside. This form is loaded inside an iframe (id = "myFrame") of my Edit page. The edit page has a modal popup with the iframe. When I click a button in the modal popup of the edit page, I call $("#myFrame").contents().find("#myButton").click() in my javascript file.

My question is, when I call .click() of the button, why doesn't it fire my client-side validations in IE8? I tried it on chrome and it works fine.

I've already wasted 3 days searching for an answer but so far I came up with nothing. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Little optimization, but you turn $("#myFrame").contents().find(#myButton").click() into $(#myButton").click()

Comment: I remember doing that and it didn't work because the button is inside an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Events can get tricky and behave differently in different browsers. Try this one:

```
$("#myButton").trigger("click");
```

or

```
jQuery.event.trigger("click", button);
```

Comment: I tried the first one before and it didn't work. Let me try that second one later. Hope this works.

Comment: @user2533730 also turn on client errors in your IE8 and make sure there is no javascript error before/during the validators are triggered (there was a known issues with IE where validator event is not defined when triggered programatically)

Comment: Thing is, when I click myButton inside the iframe it works ok even on IE8. But when I click the button in my modal dialog which calls .onclick, that's where the problem happens. I am sure there are no javascript errors before the validators are triggered but during--that one I need to check.

Comment: I tried both and both of them doesn't work. There are no javascript errors. Does anyone else have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: When you say it works in iframe and not in popup the only thing that would be the issue is your jquery selector $('...'). Can you debug and confirm that the jquery variable has at least one object (button) in the list before you call "click"? (in other words separate your code into multiple lines)